# How to "pre-escape" characters in attribute values in HXT (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, hxt

How can I pre-escape `&&` so that the output of HXT contains literal `&&` characters instead of `&amp;&amp;`?

Example Code snippet:

```
mkelem "div" [sattr "ng-show" "canEdit && isAdmin"] [ ... ]
```

This code generates output like:

```
<div ng-show="canEdit amp;&amp; isAdmin">
```

I would like the output to be this instead:

```
<div ng-show="canEdit && isAdmin">
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. I switched the `writeDocument` options from using `withOutputXHTML` to `withOutputPLAIN`. Then the `&&` in the attributes are not escaped.